# PHP MySQL Connection Timed Out on private network

Tags: mysql, nginx, php

I am getting intermittent 'Connection Timed Out' errors when a php script on my web server connects to the MySQL database server over the private network. However, if I tell the script to use the public network to connect, these errors do not appear.

My connection script is setup so that whenever I try to connect to mysql, it checks for errors, if there is an error, it sends me an email then automatically switches to the public network to try that connection. If the public connection fails, it sends me another email and displays a custom web page to the user.

I get about 5 to 10 connection errors every hour. There are hundreds of successful connections every minute.

These machines are dedicated machines. I contacted our hosting company and they tested the routers and cables and said everything is fine. I tried pinging the servers both ways and there are no errors at all for test periods over an hour.

I am using the latest Nginx with the latest PHP and PHP-FPM. Mysql is 5.5.27. These are Centos 6 64bit systems with that latest updates.

I've tried many network configuration options, adjustments to php-fpm & mysql config file and no matter what I do or change, nothing fixes it.

The weird thing is, everything works great over the public network and pings and file transfer work great over the private network between both machines.

Any ideas?

** UPDATE **

I made some changes to the PHP-FPM config file and to the MySQL config file and the errors are now about 2 to 3 per hour but still unresolved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is your case but still worth mentioning as it helped me in a similar situation. Basically, there is a cap on max number of connections in linux kernel: https://serverfault.com/questions/10852/what-limits-the-maximum-number-of-connections-on-a-linux-server

Not sure if it is shared between all the networks, but if you think it's worth checking I'd just raise those variable values say twice and see if it had any effect on how frequently the error happens.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I tried your suggestion and it didn't help.